# How to perform bulk insert records and update existing rows if record exists from Csv file into SQL Server table using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, csv

I am trying to insert thousands of records from a `.csv` file into a SQL Server table. My `.csv` file has more than one hundred columns.

I found many articles about `SqlBulkCopy`, but in the given examples there are always 3 or 4 columns max. so mapping `.csv` columns with table columns is a big headache in my case. Please, can anyone suggest how to perform a bulk copy when the `.csv` has a lot of columns?

Articles I found:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/SqlBulkCopy--Bulk-Insert-records-and-Update-existing-rows-if-record-exists-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Does this need to be fast, lightweight, or is simply getting the records in the database acceptable?

Comment: have you tried table value parameter in SQL server? Table value parameter is premium solution.

Comment: You don't need to know the column names in advance in order to map them. If the source fields are in the same order as the target columns, you don't need to map at all. If the column names are the same, but the order is different, you can use a simple loop to add mappings where source and target name are the same.

Comment: @AdilAnsari what do TVPs have to do with *this* question? If you can *wtite* a TVP, you can *write* the column names. Besides, TVPs are *not* used for bulk inserts. They result in simple inserts. Worse, they have to send all the data at once, where SqlBulkCopy can batch the data and send them as fast as possible

Comment: no idea.could you plz explain in detail

Comment: @sam what is the schema of the source file and target table? How do you load the CSV? Is there any relation between souce and target column names? Please post your code, it's impossible to guess what may or may not be wrong

Comment: If you have 100 input columns, and 100 destination columns, how do you expect to get the right data in the right column without doing any column mapping? Yes adding 100 column mappings is a bit tedious, but with the help of copy and paste, this is probably a 5 minute job, and it only needs to be done once, so my opinion would be that the most robust solution is to take a bit of time now, do the mapping properly with SQL Bulk Copy, and reap the rewards in the future.

Comment: In addition, if you want a solution that updates existing records then you probably need to insert into a staging table, and UPSERT the records from the staging table to the main table.

Comment: @GarethD you won't need to write the mappings if they match the table names, eg you can iterate over a DataTable's columns and use the same name as the source and target name of the mapping. If they don't match, then perhaps a staging table with *matching* column names is needed

Comment: Actually based on the csv file columns I created the sql table.Obviously both will be match.

Comment: source and destination columns are same and in same order. so How i can I move forward?

Comment: It may be easy to write a batch file using sqlcmd.exe which comes with sql server.  See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine

Comment: You could just get a CSV reading library that can reference columns via index number, read x number of lines at a time and performing the updates yourself via direct sql. Is there some complicated step I'm missing here?